# How to implement this Java interface in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-interop

Since Kotlin doesn't have primitives, how could this interface be implemented?

```
public interface A {
  @NotNull Object get(@NotNull Integer i);
  @NotNull Object get(int i);
}
```

I cannot change the Java code since it's a compiled class file in a binary library.

Comment: What was the problem with `fun get(i: Integer /* or Integer? */) = ...; fun get(i: Int) = ...`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If a single implementation, as in [@zsmb13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4465208/zsmb13)'s answer, is not enough for you and you need separate implementations for the two methods in Kotlin, then you can add an intermediate interface overriding the method accepting `Integer` with a nullable parameter:

```
private interface IntermediateA : A {
    override fun get(i: Int?): Any
}
```

Implementing this interface instead of the original `A`,  the Kotlin compiler will distinguish the two methods, allowing you to override them as follows:

```
class C : IntermediateA {
    override fun get(i: Int) = "primitive"
    override fun get(i: Int?) = "boxed"
}
```

```
val a: A = C()
println(a.get(1)) // primitive
println(a.get(1 as Int?)) // boxed
```

---

If you had access to the Java code, you could fix this by adding a nullability annotation to the method accepting the boxed type:

```
Object get(@Nullable Integer i);
```

The Kotlin compiler understands different kinds of nullability annotations, [here's the list](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations).

Answer (score 11):

Implementing just one method that takes `Int` as its parameter works, and can be called from either Kotlin or Java.

```
class B : A {

    override fun get(i: Int): Any {
        return "something"
    }

}
```

If you decompile the bytecode, you'll see that the Kotlin compiler is smart enough to create both methods, with one of them just redirecting to the real implementation.

[image: Decompiled bytecode example]

One possible problem is that you can't make the method take `Int?`, and it will crash with a `NullPointerException` on the `.intValue()` call if it's called from Java like so:

```
B b = new B();
Integer i = null;
b.get(i);
```

I'm not sure if there's a way to solve for that use case.

**Edit:** hotkey's answer has rest of the answers in it.

Comment: What if I have two entirely different implementations depending on whether it's `int` or `Integer`? How to get that differentiation in Kotlin?

Comment: It seems like that might not be possible in this exact case. In general, you could differentiate these by declaring a method that takes `Int` to handle primitives and another that takes `Int?` that handles the boxed type.

Comment: Fine, I got your point. But I cannot grasp why boxed one won't be immediately dispatched to `Int` provided it's value is **not** `null`.

Comment: There is a way, but it requires the Java method parameter to be annotated as `@Nullable`. With no access to the Java code, it seems to be possible only with an intermediate Java interface, see the other answer.

Comment: Actually, a Kotlin intermediate interface is enough (overriding only one function with `Int?` paramater type).

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin, we can declare:

- **primitive** int as : `Int`
- **boxed** int as : `Int?`

Your interface can be simplified to:

```
private interface ModifiedA : A {
    override fun get(i: Int?): Any
}
```

In Kotlin, if you implement this modified interface then Kotlin will provide you two methods to override. One for primitive type and another one for boxed type.

```
class ImplementationOfA : ModifiedA {
    override fun get(i: Int)
    override fun get(i: Int?)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I write a simple demo in Java.

then convert it to Kotlin with Kotlin plugins in IntelliJ IDEA or Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

add these lines to implement interface in kotlin

```
class abc : AppCompatActivity(), interface 1, interface 2,
{
override fun get(i: Int?): Any
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How's `AppCompatActivity` relevant?