# While loop doesn't seem to work with .putFile when uploading multiple images to Firebase storage in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, firebase-storage

I have been trying to upload multiple images to `Firebase` Storage. But, I am not able to do it successfully. I could successfully upload the image (single) to the storage and add the URL of the image to the `Firestore`, now that I revised my code to upload up to five images, it could be any number of images from 1 to 5.

```
    R.id.btn_submit -> {
    if (validateDetails()) {
        uploadImage()
    }
}
```

The above code, calls the following function after validating the fields,  which then calls the function `uploadImageToCloudStorage`.  `mSelectedImageFileUriList` is `private var mSelectedImageFileUriList: MutableList<Uri?>? = null`. It all seems to work correctly.

```
    private fun uploadImage() {
    showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
    FirestoreClass().uploadImageToCloudStorage(
        this@AddProductActivity,
        mSelectedImageFileUriList,
        Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE,
        Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME,
        et_product_title.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
    )
}
```

Following code is where I guess is a mistake.

```
    fun uploadImageToCloudStorage(
     activity: AddProductActivity,
     imageFileURI: MutableList<Uri?>?,
     imageType: String,
     directoryName: String,
     title: String
 ) {

     var i = 0
     val imageURLList = ArrayList<String>()
     val itr = imageFileURI?.iterator()

     if (itr != null) {

         while (itr.hasNext()) {

             val sRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(
                 "/$directoryName/" + imageType + "." + Constants.getFileExtension(
                     activity,
                     imageFileURI[i]
                 )
             )
            
             sRef.putFile(imageFileURI[i]!!)
                 .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->  
                     taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
                         .addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                             
                             if (i < imageFileURI.size) {
                                 i += 1
                                 imageURLList.add(uri.toString())

                             } else {
                                 activity.imageUploadSuccess(imageURLList)
                             }
                         }
                 }
                 .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                     activity.hideProgressDialog()
                   Log.e(
                         activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                         exception.message,
                         exception
                     )
                 }

         }
     } else {
         Toast.makeText(
             activity,
             "There is no images in the ArrayList of URI",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
         ).show()
     }
 }
```

**EDIT: After receiving the first answer.**

I have created a `QueueSyn.kt` file and added the code in the Answer. The activity where the images and the button are changed to

`class AddProductActivity : BaseActivity(), View.OnClickListener, QueueSyncCallback {`

The following function is called when the button is hit.

```
    private fun uploadProductImage() {

    showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))

   QueueSync(
        mSelectedImageFileUriList,
        Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE,
        Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME,
        et_product_title.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
        this
    ).startUploading()

}
```

I have also implemented these two methods in the class `AddProductActivity`, but I don't know what should go inside this.

```
    override fun completed(successList: MutableList<Uri>, failureList: MutableList<Uri>) {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}

override fun getFileExtension(uri: Uri): String {
    TODO("Not yet implemented")
}
```

**Error:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there any error message? If there is please edit.

Comment: Maybe try sending files one by one

Comment: I am sending one by one with `sRef.putFile(imageFileURI[i]!!)` where 'i' is the index of the `uri` in the `MutableList` called 'imageFileURI'. Do you mean something else? I do not know if the way I iterate is wrong, I am not a pro.

Comment: What you are doing here is your while loop is iterating over all the files and inside it firebase storage is sending files async which means before a file is sent fully another one starts uploading. This way is not going to sustain in case you have a long list of files. What you should instead try is maybe use a recursive solution to synchronise file upload so only one is uploaded at a time or you can use a custom queue which uploads five or more files at once and then tries to upload the rest

Comment: OK, I got you. But I don't know how to do that. Could you help me modify my code?

Comment: Sure let me cook something up.

Comment: Try the edited answer

Comment: Error is updated in the question, please check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234819/discussion-between-rahul-rawat-and-codist).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
import android.net.Uri
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

interface QueueSyncCallback {
    fun completed(successList: MutableList<Uri>, failureList: MutableList<Uri>)
    fun getFileExtension(uri: Uri): String
}

class QueueSync(
    imageFileURI: MutableList<Uri?>?,
    private val imageType: String,
    private val directoryName: String,
    private val title: String,
    private val callback: QueueSyncCallback,
    private val maxActive: Int = 5
) {
    private val queue: LinkedList<Uri> = LinkedList()
    private val runningQueue: MutableList<Uri> = Collections.synchronizedList(
        object : ArrayList<Uri>() {
            override fun remove(element: Uri): Boolean {
                val removed = super.remove(element)

                if (isEmpty() && queue.isEmpty()) {
                    callback.completed(successList, failureList)
                } else if (queue.isNotEmpty()) {
                    addToRunningQueue()
                }
                return removed
            }
        }
    )
    private val successList: MutableList<Uri> = Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList())
    private val failureList: MutableList<Uri> = Collections.synchronizedList(ArrayList())

    init {
        if (imageFileURI != null)
            for (uri in imageFileURI) {
                if (uri != null)
                    queue.add(uri)
            }
    }

    private fun getLocation(uri: Uri) = "/$directoryName/$imageType.${callback.getFileExtension(uri)}"

    fun startUploading() {
        var i = 0

        if (queue.isEmpty()) {
            callback.completed(successList, failureList)
            return
        }

        while (i < maxActive && queue.isNotEmpty()) {
            addToRunningQueue()
            i++
        }
    }

    private fun addToRunningQueue() {
        val uri = queue.poll()!!
        runningQueue.add(uri)
        uploadImageToCloudStorage(uri)
    }

    private fun uploadImageToCloudStorage(locationUri: Uri) {
        val sRef: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference(getLocation(locationUri))

        sRef.putFile(locationUri)
            .addOnSuccessListener { taskSnapshot ->
                taskSnapshot.metadata!!.reference!!.downloadUrl
                    .addOnSuccessListener { uri ->
                        successList.add(uri)
                        runningQueue.remove(locationUri)
                    }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                failureList.add(locationUri)
                runningQueue.remove(locationUri)
            }
    }
}
```

Since your need requires usage of threads so to prevent race conditions I had to use `Collections.synchronizedList`. To use this you need to implement QueueSyncCallback in your activity and pass it as a reference to QueueSync. Make sure that any piece of code written inside `completed` is wrapped inside `runOnMainThread` if it is going to access views in any way since `completed` will not run on main thread as far as I know. This should work however I am not able to test it since it is based on your current code.

**Edit:-** Answering after edit

```
override fun completed(successList: MutableList<Uri>, failureList: MutableList<Uri>) {
    imageUploadSuccess(successList)
    hideProgressDialog()
}

override fun getFileExtension(uri: Uri): String {
    Constants.getFileExtension(this, imageFileURI[i])
}
```

Comment: If it works leave an upvote and accept this answer for others.

Comment: Sure, I will. I do not know where to start now. Let me check how to use code. Can you give me a hint? I am not an expert in it.

Comment: Just add this as a kt file and make QueueSync object after that just call startUploading on it

Comment: OK, I am trying. What value should be passed for the parameter `callback` when I call `startUploading`. This is how I am doing it. `QueueSync(
            mSelectedImageFileUriList,
            Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE,
            Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME,
            et_product_title.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' },
        ).startUploading()`


Also, "property 'title` is never used". Is something missing?

Comment: you will have to implement `QueueSyncCallback` in your activity and send `this` as callback

Comment: I read that in your answer and been trying for that.

Comment: Maybe read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44132574/how-to-implement-this-java-interface-in-kotlin)

Comment: I went through the link you have given and a couple of other tutorials and I am learning now. Can you look at my question after 'Edit'. Thank you so much for your time and effort.

Comment: Your code worked like a charm. Needed not a single edit or correction. It was awesome. I took more time because many things in your code were new to me. You have been so helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: Can you take a look at my new question? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/q/68450099/13935956